# Contact info in a scientific paper

Tags: lists, indentation

I'm writing a scientific paper and I came to the last part of it which is listing the info and contact info of the authors. I wrote the following code:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item[{}] 
 \textsc{
 Yasser Ibrahim\\
 Department of Mathematics\\
 Faculty of Science\\
 Cairo University\\
 Giza, Egypt\\
 {\small And}\\
 Department of Mathematics\\
 Faculty of Science\\
 Taibah University\\
 Madina, Saudi Arabia\\
 }
 \textit{Email address}: 
 \texttt{\href{mailto:yfibrahim@sci.cu.edu.eg}{yfibrahim@sci.cu.edu.eg}}, 
 \texttt{\href{mailto:yabdelwahab@taibahu.edu.sa}{yabdelwahab@taibahu.edu.sa}}

\item[{}]
 \textsc{
 Hussein Eid\\
 Department of Mathematics\\
 Faculty of Science\\
 Cairo University\\
 Giza, Egypt\\
 }
 \textit{Email address}: \texttt{\href{mailto:heid@sci.cu.edu.eg} 
 {heid@sci.cu.edu.eg}}
\end{enumerate}
```

which produces something as shown in the screenshot below
[image]

It looks fine but unfortunately the name of the first author (Yasser) is not indented correctly to be precisely under the word (Department) in the next line (the same thing for the second author).

How can I overcome this problem?! Is there an alternative good approach to list the authors and their info.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to add a `%` symbol: `\textsc{%`. Otherwise you are adding a space.

Comment: Thanks a lot @SandyG